# How to pass data from parent process to child's stdin using pipe in c/c++?

Tags: c++, process, pipe, fork

### Original question

Hey, everyone, I am currently learning how to manage processes in C/C++ with the unistd.h library.
Here is the scheme of what I am trying to do.
[image]

I use `fork()` function to create a new process. Parent collects user input and sends it to pipe1, after that with `dup2()` the pipe1 is redirected to child's stdin. The child gets the data and performs some operation, after which outputs the result in the output file.
Here is what my `main` code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

auto main() -> int
{
    int fd[2]; // fd[0] - read; fd[1] - write
    // Creating pipe and checking that it was created
    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Pipe creation failed\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Forking the process
    int id = fork();
    if (id == -1) // fork error
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not fork a process";
        return 2;
    }
    else if (id == 0) // child process
    {
        int status;
        waitpid(getppid(), &status, 0);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        execlp("./calculator", "./calculator", NULL);
        std::cerr << "Failed to run child";
        return 3;
    }
    else // parent process
    {
        std::string number;

        while (std::cin >> number)
        {

            std::cout << "I read from user to parent: " << number << "\n";
            if (write(fd[1], &number, sizeof(number)) == -1)
            {
                std::cerr << "Could not write into pipe\n";
                return 4;
            }
        }
        close(fd[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the code for my child process which is launched via `execlp()`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

auto main() -> int
{
    std::ofstream output;
    output.open("./output.txt");
    int received;
    int sum = 0;

    while (std::cin >> received)
    {
        output << "I read from parent to child: " << received << "\n";
    }
}
```

When I run `calculator` executable separately everything works well, but as soon as I try to run `main`, I only get the messages from parent process that the read was successful, but no output data from the child. I suspect that I somehow use the pipe  or dup2 wrong, but I have no clue how to make it right. Please, help!

Comment: You can only use `waitpid()` to wait for a child process. The child can't wait for its parent. And you don't want to wait for the parent, because the parent doesn't exit until it gets EOF on its standard input.

Comment: The parent process needs to `close(fd[0])` and the child needs to `close(fd[1])`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Removed waitpid() and added close(fd[0]) and close(fd[1]) where needed, but still no output from the child

Comment: The parent sends the number with `write()` which is binary.  You're trying to read the number with `cin >> received` in the child, which is formatted extraction and will get horribly confused when it encounters binary data instead of text.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing it out. I'll try to substitute `cin >> received` to `read()` and see what happens

Comment: OMG, it worked, just needed to substitute to `read()` and now it works perfectly! Thank you so much @BenVoigt, been stuck at it for hours!

Comment: Cancelled the closure as duplicate because OP is sending a number, not a string, and the difference ended up being quite important.

Comment: @Demo_13B: Now your homework is to write a nice answer to your own question.  I suggest temporarily changing your `exec` call to run `xxd` or `hexdump`, then you'll get a very clear illustration of the fact that the data is binary.

Answer (score 0):

Per [POSIX `waitpid()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `wait()` and `waitpid()` functions shall obtain status information pertaining to one of the caller's child processes. ...

Note "the caller's child processes".

You are calling `waitpid()` **from** the child process, waiting for the **parent** process:

```
else if (id == 0) // child process
{
    int status;
    waitpid(getppid(), &status, 0);
```

It's impossible to say what's actually happening without more detail, but I suspect your child process could be hanging in the `waitpid()` call for a signal that will never come.

Comment: Thank you, I just figured that parent process would need to write to pipe before child executes. Removed waitpid(), but still no output from the child

Comment: It won't hang, it will return an error.

Comment: The same documentation says it returns the `ECHILD` errno code if the PID is not a child.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Shoutout to @BenVoigt for figuring out the problem. The problem was that the data that was put into pipe with `write()` function. Which means that stdin for child contained binary data which can be illustrated by changing `exec()` to call `xxd` as suggested by @BenVoigt. Here is the output you get:

```
1 2 3 4
I read from user to parent: 1
I read from user to parent: 2
I read from user to parent: 3
I read from user to parent: 4
00000000: 0231 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .1..............
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0232 0000 0000 0000  .........2......
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0233 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .3..............
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0234 0000 0000 0000  .........4......
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

But my child tried to read data with `std::cin >> received` which expected text but not binary data. Instead I changed it to `read()` function, which now correctly interprets input data. Here is my fixed child code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

auto main() -> int
{
    std::ofstream output;
    output.open("./output.txt");
    std::string received;
    int sum = 0;

    while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &received, sizeof(received)) != 0)
    {
        output << "I read from parent to child: " << received << "\n";
        sum += std::stoi(received);
    }

    output << "Sum is: " << sum << "\n";
}
```

And now my function finally works and this is the output that I get in the file:

```
I read from parent to child: 1
I read from parent to child: 4
I read from parent to child: 2
Sum is: 7
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: `while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &received, sizeof(received)) != 0)` is not the proper way to do it. You should add up the returned value from `read` (if positive) and keep calling `read` until you've read `sizeof(received)` bytes. You are not guaranteed to get all the bytes in one call to `read`.